# I want to build a linux image using yocto, image size needs to small. I am using a SOM from phytec

Tags: linux, som, imx8

First I went through the Phy tech getting started guide, and Performed a BSP build successfully.
Link is : https://www.phytec.de/cdocuments/?doc=LAC7Ig#L1017e-A4phyCOREi-MX8MPlusBSPManual-TFTPServerSetup
Final image size is big, it around 597 MB. I want to reduce this.
It has lots of unwanted packages.
I want to have only the packages which I want.

First I though of editing the machine variable in local.conf file in build/conf folder.
I tried to make a copy of machine .conf file which is already available and which came from phytec BSP repo.
Then , if I give that name and build, I am getting.
an error message :

```
|   /home/rabi/yocto/build/tmp/work/pytec_rabi_imx8mp-phytec-linux/u-boot-imx/2022.04-r0/git/tools/binman/binman   --toolpath ./tools  build -u -d u-boot.dtb -O . -m --allow-missing --fake-ext-blobs -I . -I /home/rabi/yocto/build/tmp/work/pytec_rabi_imx8mp-phytec-linux/u-boot-imx/2022.04-r0/git -I /home/rabi/yocto/build/tmp/work/pytec_rabi_imx8mp-phytec-linux/u-boot-imx/2022.04-r0/git/board/phytec/phycore_imx8mp -I arch/arm/dts -a of-list="imx8mp-phyboard-pollux-rdk"  -a atf-bl31-path= -a tee-os-path= -a opensbi-path= -a default-dt="imx8mp-phyboard-pollux-rdk" -a scp-path= -a spl-bss-pad= -a tpl-bss-pad=1 -a spl-dtb=y -a tpl-dtb=
| /home/rabi/yocto/build/tmp/work/pytec_rabi_imx8mp-phytec-linux/u-boot-imx/2022.04-r0/git/tools/binman/binman:12: DeprecationWarning: The distutils package is deprecated and slated for removal in Python 3.12. Use setuptools or check PEP 632 for potential alternatives
|   from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib
| /home/rabi/yocto/build/tmp/work/pytec_rabi_imx8mp-phytec-linux/u-boot-imx/2022.04-r0/git/tools/binman/binman:12: DeprecationWarning: The distutils.sysconfig module is deprecated, use sysconfig instead
|   from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib
| Traceback (most recent call last):
|   File "/home/rabi/yocto/build/tmp/work/pytec_rabi_imx8mp-phytec-linux/u-boot-imx/2022.04-r0/git/tools/binman/binman", line 53, in <module>
|     from binman import control
|   File "/home/rabi/yocto/build/tmp/work/pytec_rabi_imx8mp-phytec-linux/u-boot-imx/2022.04-r0/git/tools/binman/control.py", line 11, in <module>
|     import pkg_resources
| ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pkg_resources'
| make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/rabi/yocto/build/tmp/work/pytec_rabi_imx8mp-phytec-linux/u-boot-imx/2022.04-r0/build/phycore-imx8mp_defconfig'
| make[1]: *** [/home/rabi/yocto/build/tmp/work/pytec_rabi_imx8mp-phytec-linux/u-boot-imx/2022.04-r0/git/Makefile:1095: all] Error 1
| make: *** [Makefile:177: sub-make] Error 2
| make: Leaving directory '/home/rabi/yocto/build/tmp/work/pytec_rabi_imx8mp-phytec-linux/u-boot-imx/2022.04-r0/git'
| ERROR: oe_runmake failed
| WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
ERROR: Task (/home/rabi/yocto/sources/poky/../meta-imx/meta-bsp/recipes-bsp/u-boot/u-boot-imx_2022.04.bb:do_compile) failed with exit code '1'
Waiting for 1 running task to finish:
0: linux-imx-5.15.71+gitAUTOINC+50912be386-r0 do_compile - 1m17s (pid 747099
```